# Ionic - APK Build always produces old apk with old values

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, apk, capacitor

I am currently developing an Ionic app with Capacitor. Strangely, the apk produces unexpected results.

This happened fairly often. Let me describe what I do.

When building the apk, I first make sure to delete the `server` key in capacitor.config.json. It is written there when I use Ionic Live Reload.

Then I use following commands to build the apk:

1. `ionic build`
2. `ionic cap copy`
3. `ionic cap sync`
4. `ionic cap open android`

Before I click the Play Button to install the app on my device, I go to my settings and clear the cache and data of the app, followed by a uninstallation of the app.

Then I install the new app on my phone. But strangely there are old values and also some old values from the internal database.

How could this happen? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "OrgAtwork_mobile",
  "version": "0.08.06",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.14",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.10.24",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-preferences": "^0.99.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ionic-long-press": "^2.0.3",
    "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "sha.js": "^2.4.11",
    "tslib": "^2.0.1",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.4",
    "underscore": "^1.11.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.14",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.3.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

Comment: `ionic cap copy` is to be used when you have made changes to the code. `ionic cap sync` should be used when you have added/removed plugins from the project, this will sync your code changes as well.. use either of these, but both together are just wasting precious time.

Comment: try direct ionic cap run android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In the Android Manifest, set`android:allowBackup="false"`. Its true by default and will load some old data when its not set to false.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by deleting the `android` and `dist` folder inside the ionic app. Then I ran:

```
npm run build
ionic capacitor add android
ionic capacitor open android’
```

Update:
You can also without deleting the folders do the following steps:

```
npm run build
npx cap sync
ionic capacitor open android
(In android studio) sync project with gradle files
```